# How can I report a cheater?

Tags: dayz-2012

I was watching the a live stream of someone playing DayZ while he was going back to his tent and it showed a bunch of forbidden item such as the M24 Desert and AS50 TWS.

I could not see the server or his nick name since he hid it on the stream.  However, I do know the location of his stash:

- 103 117 and the time was 7/17/12 15:00±5hours.

(The tent area was in the water located at Topolka Dam)

There were also some phenomena nearby that I saw in the video

- In the north side of Elecktro, there was a forest fire which set up 60~120m height of black smoke.

Is this sufficient information to report or locate the cheater?

Answer (score 3):

Your information is *not* sufficient to report the player because you don't know the server name or address. The guidelines for reporting cheaters are [posted in a sticky](http://dayzmod.com/forum/index.php?/topic/5297-cheat-report-guidelines/) on the DayZ forums. If you can gather the minimum required info, you can report the cheater in the [Cheat Reporting section of those forums](http://dayzmod.com/forum/index.php?/forum/32-cheat-reporting/).

**Required Information:**

- Server where cheating occurred.
- Time that it happened including your timezone.
- What happened during the incident.

**Optional:**

- Video proof
- Pictures

Answer (score 2):

You can report cheaters by using the official community forums:
[Cheat Reporting - Day Z Forums](http://dayzmod.com/forum/index.php?/forum/32-cheat-reporting/)

**EDIT:**
Sorry, I didn't see the end of the question, I do not know if this is sufficient evidence to report the cheater, just post a thread and see what they say.  I personally do not play this mod, so I wouldn't know myself.  All I know is that this game suffers greatly from cheaters.